# How to extract only the epoch details and leave other things out in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, epoch

I have a dataset with *time* in the epoch. I need to extract the epoch *time* and convert it into normal *DD MM YYYY* format along with time details in *HH: MM* format.
The column is like this:-

```
Index       Date                                                                  
0        {'$date': {'$numberLong': '1562005805010'}}
```

I have tried using regex, extract and replace methods but they convert the date column to NaN

```
df1['date'] = df1['date'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)
```

I want only epochs to be displayed so that they can be converted to date and time.
[Here is the column that I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX2D7.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If values are strings first convert it to dictioanries by `ast.literal_eval` and then select:

```
print (type(df['Date'].iat[0]))
<class 'str'>

import ast

s = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)['$date']['$numberLong'])
```

If values are nested dicts only select by keys:

```
print (type(df['Date'].iat[0]))
<class 'dict'>

s = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x['$date']['$numberLong'])
```

And last use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `unit` parameter:

```
print (s)
0    1562005805010
Name: Date, dtype: object

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(s, unit='ms')
print (df)
   Index                    Date
0      0 2019-07-01 18:30:05.010
```

Comment: When in the data I only have $numberLong and not $date, this code doesn't work

Comment: @AbhasMehrotra - then change `x['$date']['$numberLong']` to `x['$numberLong']`

Comment: I did exactly that here is the error   "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" and the code I use is "df2['date'] = df2['date'].apply(lambda x:x['$numberLong'])"